# A way to complete for loop before next operation

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, for-loop

I have a big array of objects that i got from my rest api and i want to search for a value from one of the elements.
I managed to come up with a method that searches the words but it works for a few words and not all. when i tried to find out the problem i realised that the for loop doesnot go through the whole array.
below is my code

```
function search(nameKey, myArray) {
    var lowercased_array = [];
    //lowercase the search value
    var lowercased_nameKey = nameKey.toLowerCase()
    //lowercase the searched array
    for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
        myArray[i].name = myArray[i].name.toLowerCase()
        lowercased_array.push(myArray[i])
    }

    var new_array = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < lowercased_array.length; i++) {
        if ((lowercased_array[i].name).includes(lowercased_nameKey)) {
            new_array.push(lowercased_array[i])
        }
    }
    return new_array
}
```

i first turn the search word to lowercase , my first for loop is to turn the values for the name element in the array objects to lower case so that the search can take place.
The second for loop is to check if the search value exists in the name element of the objects in the array and if true push the whole object in a new array.
i am asking for help on how to ensure that the process is complete before returning the new array with the search results.

Thanks in advance

Comment: input sample with expected output, please

Comment: "*I realised that the for loop doesnot go through the whole array.*" - sure it does, no problem in the code you posted. Why do you think it doesn't? Please post an example call with input values that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: `return myArray.filter(el => el.name.toLowerCase().includes(nameKey.toLowerCase()));`

Comment: Your code is synchronous--meaning that all the loops and the arrays are fully processed before it returns.  Are you sure your entire array is loaded before entering the search function?

Comment: @Bergi it doesnt return an array with the values from the api

Comment: @Russ yes the entire array is loaded

Comment: @alsongsule What API?

Comment: @Bergi i get values from an internal api which i then pass through the argument as myArray.

Comment: @alsongsule Please [edit] your question to include that code. How did you confirm that the internal api returns the proper value? Where did you use the result of your function call?

Answer (score 0):

In general you can simplify your code.
If you use filter you could do it like that.

```
function search(nameKey, myArray) {
    
    var lowercased_nameKey = nameKey.toLowerCase()

    var new_array = myArray.filter(item => item.name.toLowerCase().includes(lowercased_nameKey))
   
    return new_array
}
```

Comment: oh yeah, didn't saw he used includes. Edited

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear why you are creating a `lowercased_array`, because you already set lowercased values in the provided Array. That being said, your function could probably use [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

```
function search(nameKey, myArray) {
  const lowercased_nameKey = nameKey.toLowerCase();
  return myArray.filter(item => item.name.toLowerCase().includes(lowercased_nameKey));
}
```